# SCRIPT16389: SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. Edge Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, microsoft-edge

I know that some other questions posted are related to this topic but their answers don't help me.
I'm trying to implement battleship in js and while debugging I get SCRIPT16389: SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. in the microsoft edge  console. 
Here's my js code so far: (I'm a beginner in javascript so sorry if serious mistakes)

```
var board = null;
var boats = null;
var rows = 8;
var columns = 8;
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
    boats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("boats"));

    console.log(boats);
    if(boats===null){
      boats = [
       {size:2, letter:'f', name:'fragate'},
       {size:3, letter:'b', name:'buque'},
       {size:3, letter:'s', name:'submarine'},
       {size:4, letter:'d', name:'destructor'},
       {size:5, letter:'p', name:'portplanes'},

     ];
     localStorage.setItem("boats", JSON.stringify(boats));

    }
    rows = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("rows"));
    columns = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("columns"));
    if(isNaN(rows)|| isNaN(columns)){
      rows = 8;
      columns = 8;
      localStorage.setItem("rows", 8);
      localStorage.setItem("columns", 8);
    }
  }else {
    console.log("We don't have localStorage")
  }
});
function createMatrix(row,col){
  var matrix;
  matrix = new Array(row);
  for (var i=0; i<row; i++){
    matriz[i] = new Array(col);
  }
  return matrix;
}
function createFullMatrix(row,col,inside){
  var matrix = new Array(row);
  for(var i=0; i<row; i++){
    matrix[i] = new Array(col);
    for(var j=0; j<col; j++){
      matrix[i][j]=inside;
    }
  }
  return matrix;
}
function matrix2console(matrix){
  var aux;
  for(var i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
    aux = "";
    for(var j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++){
      aux+=matrix[i][j]+'\t';
    }
    console.log(aux);
  }
}
function createBoard(){
  var html='<table>';
  for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
    html+='<tr>';
    for (var j=0; j<columns; j++){
      html+='<td id="cel_'+i+'_'+j+'" class = "water"+ onclick=shoot("celd_'+i+'_'+j+'",'+i+','+j+')></td>';
    }
    html+='</tr>';
  }
  html+='</table>'
  document.getElementById("match").innerHTML=html;
}
function createBoardjQ(){
  $("#match").empty();
  var table = $("<table />");
  for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
    var row = $("<tr/>");
    for(var j=0; j<columns; j++){
      var celd = $('<td id="celd_'+i+'_'+j+'" onclick=shoot("celd_'+i+'_'+j+'",'+i+','+j+') > </td>');
      celd.addClass("water");
      row.append(celd);
    }
    table.append(row);
  }
  $("#match").append(table);

}
function createMatch(){
  board = createMatrix(rows,columns);
  startMatrix('a',board);
  setBoats(board);
  createBoardjQ();
  matrix2console(board);
}
function shoot(celd, i, j){
  switch (board[i][j]) {
    case 'a':
           board[i][j]= 'A';
           $('#'+celd).removeClass('water');
           $('#'+celd).addClass('miss')

break;
    case 'b':
           board[i][j]= 'B';
           $('#'+celd).removeClass('water');
           $('#'+celd).addClass('boats')

break;
    case 'd':
           board[i][j]= 'd';
           $('#'+celd).removeClass('water');
           $('#'+celd).addClass('boats')
           break;

      case 'f':
             board[i][j]= 'F';
             $('#'+celd).removeClass('water');
             $('#'+celd).addClass('boats')

 break;
 case 'p':
        board[i][j]= 'P';
        $('#'+celd).removeClass('water');
        $('#'+celd).addClass('boats')

break;
case 's':
       board[i][j]= 'S';
       $('#'+celd).removeClass('water');
       $('#'+celd).addClass('boats')

break;
  }
}
function startMatrix(data, matrix){
  for(var i=0; i<matrix.length;){
    for(var j=0; j<matrix[i].length;){
      matrix[i][j]=data;
    }
  }
}
function dice(value){
  var random;
  random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(value));
  return random;
}
function coin(){
  return (dice(2));
}
function setBoats(matrix){
 for (var i=0; i<boats.length; i++){
   var boats = boats[i];

   do{
     var free=true;
     var direction = coin();
     if(!direction){
       var row = dice(matrix.length);
       var col = dice(matrix[row].length-boat.size);
       for(var j=0; j<boat.size;j++){
         if(matrix[row][j]!='a'){
           free = false;
         }
       }
       if(free){
         for(var j=0; j<boat.size; j++){
           matrix[row][j+col]=boat.letter;
         }
       }
     }else{
       var row = dice(matrix.length-boat.size);
       var col = dice(matrix[row].length);
         var row = dice(matrix.length);
         var col = dice(matrix[row].length-boat.size);
         for(var j=0; j<boat.size;j++){
           if(matrix[j+row][col]!='a'){
             free = false;
           }
         }
         if(free){
           for(var j=0; j<boat.size; j++){
             matrix[j+row][col]=boat.letter;
           }
         }
     }
   }while(!free);
 }
  }
```

Comment: 189 lines of code is a *lot*. Please explain where the error occurs and post the code in a [MCVE]

Comment: What jQuery library are you using? Any other Console Errors?

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: @Twisty That's the only error, and the libraries I've imported: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lib/fastclick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lib/appframework/appframework.ui.min.js"></script> are

Comment: @Andy it actually happened in Edge 42

Comment: I see an issue in `setBoats()` function, it calls boats and then defines it again. That could be an issue.

Comment: @IrinaCrabbs upon review, it appears to be a typo, looks like you mean to have `var boat = boats[i];`

Comment: @Twisty exactly! that's what I meant , thanks for noticing, but I still have the same problem, and when onclick in the element that should load that script, the page tries to load it but it takes so much time and it does not.

Comment: @IrinaCrabbs another typo in `createMatrix()`

Comment: @Twisty which one do you mean?

Comment: You have an issue in `startMatrix()` - https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/L1m6jw5q/19/ You can see in console it's failing when executing this in `startMatch()`.

Comment: @Twisty yeah I think that the error in startMatch() is becouse it is unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference according to the console, how can I fix that?

Comment: I figured it out, your `for()` loops do not increment the counters, hence the loop goes infinite.

Comment: @Twisty yesss :/ I incremented both of them now in StartMatrix and I get unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference in the console in line 138 , 17

Comment: @Twisty actually I think a have the Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference problem in 152,15 what do you think, I don't know why though.

Comment: @IrinaCrabbs You're exceeding the matrix index length. Will post an answer in a second.

Comment: @Twisty great, now it works! although when I  shoot nothing happens , at least it is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correcting a number of typos and reviewing the logic, the primary issue reported was in `startMatrix()` where the `for` loops were not incrementing their counters. This caused an infinite loop.

Consider the following to fix:

```
function startMatrix(data, matrix) {
  var singleRow, singleCol;
  for (var r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++) {
      matrix[r][c] = data;
    }
  }
  console.log("SM: Matrix Complete", matrix);
}
```

Full example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/L1m6jw5q/58/

**HTML**

```
<div id="match">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#match td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#match .water {
  background-color: #ccf;
}

#match .miss {
  background-color: #eee;
}

#match .boats {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var board = null;
var boats = null;
var rows = 8;
var columns = 8;

function createMatrix(row, col) {
  var matrix;
  matrix = new Array(row);
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new Array(col);
  }
  console.log("CM: New Matrix Created", matrix);
  return matrix;
}

function startMatrix(data, matrix) {
  var singleRow, singleCol;
  for (var r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++) {
      matrix[r][c] = data;
    }
  }
  console.log("SM: Matrix Complete", matrix);
}

function createFullMatrix(row, col, inside) {
  var matrix = new Array(row);
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new Array(col);
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      matrix[i][j] = inside;
    }
  }
  return matrix;
}

function matrix2console(matrix) {
  var aux;
  for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    aux = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      aux += matrix[i][j] + '\t';
    }
    console.log(aux);
  }
}

function createBoardjQ() {
  $("#match").empty();
  var table = $("<table />");
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var row = $("<tr/>");
    for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      var celd = $('<td id="celd_' + i + '_' + j + '" data-shoot="celd_' + i + '_' + j + ',' + i + ',' + j + '"></td>');
      celd.addClass("water");
      row.append(celd);
    }
    table.append(row);
  }
  $("#match").append(table);
}

function createMatch() {
  console.log("CMa: Make Board");
  board = createMatrix(rows, columns);
  console.log("CMa: Start Matrix", 'a', board);
  startMatrix('a', board);
  console.log("CMa: Set Boats", board);
  setBoats(board);
  console.log("CMa: Create Board jQ");
  createBoardjQ();
  console.log("CMa: Matrix to Console");
  matrix2console(board);
}

function shoot(celd, i, j) {
  switch (board[i][j]) {
    case 'a':
      board[i][j] = 'A';
      $('#' + celd).removeClass('water');
      $('#' + celd).addClass('miss');
      console.log("Miss");
      break;
    case 'b':
      board[i][j] = 'B';
      $('#' + celd).removeClass('water');
      $('#' + celd).addClass('boats');
      console.log("Hit");
      break;
    case 'd':
      board[i][j] = 'd';
      $('#' + celd).removeClass('water');
      $('#' + celd).addClass('boats');
      console.log("Hit");
      break;
    case 'f':
      board[i][j] = 'F';
      $('#' + celd).removeClass('water');
      $('#' + celd).addClass('boats');
      console.log("Hit");
      break;
    case 'p':
      board[i][j] = 'P';
      $('#' + celd).removeClass('water');
      $('#' + celd).addClass('boats');
      console.log("Hit");
      break;
    case 's':
      board[i][j] = 'S';
      $('#' + celd).removeClass('water');
      $('#' + celd).addClass('boats');
      console.log("Hit");
      break;
  }
}

function dice(value) {
  var random;
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (value));
  return random;
}

function coin() {
  return (dice(2));
}

function setBoats(matrix) {
  var i, j, row, col, free;
  for (i = 0; i < boats.length; i++) {
    var boat = boats[i];
    do {
      free = true;
      var direction = coin();
      if (!direction) {
        row = dice(matrix.length);
        col = dice(matrix[row].length - boat.size);
        for (j = 0; j < boat.size; j++) {
          if (matrix[row][j] != 'a') {
            free = false;
          }
        }
        if (free) {
          for (j = 0; j < boat.size; j++) {
            matrix[row][j + col] = boat.letter;
          }
        }
      } else {
        row = dice(matrix.length - boat.size);
        col = dice(matrix[row].length);
        //row = dice(matrix.length);
        //col = dice(matrix[row].length - boat.size);
        for (j = 0; j < boat.size; j++) {
          var k = (j + row) >= 1 ? (j + row) - 1 : 0;
          console.log(j, row, k, boat.size);
          if (k > matrix.length) {
            free = false;
          } else {
            if (matrix[k][col] != 'a') {
              free = false;
            }
          }
        }
        if (free) {
          for (j = 0; j < boat.size; j++) {
            matrix[j + row][col] = boat.letter;
          }
        }
      }
    } while (!free);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    boats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("boats"));
    console.log(boats);

    if (boats === null) {
      boats = [{
          size: 2,
          letter: 'f',
          name: 'fragate'
        },
        {
          size: 3,
          letter: 'b',
          name: 'buque'
        },
        {
          size: 3,
          letter: 's',
          name: 'submarine'
        },
        {
          size: 4,
          letter: 'd',
          name: 'destructor'
        },
        {
          size: 5,
          letter: 'p',
          name: 'portplanes'
        },
      ];
      localStorage.setItem("boats", JSON.stringify(boats));
    }
    rows = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("rows"));
    columns = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("columns"));
    if (isNaN(rows) || isNaN(columns)) {
      rows = 8;
      columns = 8;
      localStorage.setItem("rows", 8);
      localStorage.setItem("columns", 8);
    }
    console.log(rows, columns);
    createMatch();
    $(".water").click(function(e) {
      console.log("Firing Shot", $(this));
      var c = $(this).data("shoot").split(",");
      shoot(c[0], c[1], c[2]);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("We don't have localStorage");
  }
});
```

Once the infinite loop was addressed, there was another logical error in `setBoards()`. Basically, there was a point where `j + row` would be greater than the index of `matrix`. You will want to review it and maybe even draw it out to make sure boats do not get placed off the board (which was always my favorite way to beat my brother at Battleship as a kid).

I also moved the `click` callback to jQuery. Just made it easier, so I stored the shot data in a `data` attribute for each cell. Easy to parse out and pass to `shoot()` for each click.

Hope that helps.